# Regular expression spaces in words

Tags: regex

Given:

```
<currency: word with spaces, 56>
```

and the regular expression:

```
<(?:CURRENCY):[ ]*(\w+(\s*,\s*)\d+(\s*\d+)*)>
```

What must I change to accept spaces in the "words with spaces"

Comment: Replace `\w` with `[\w\s]`, maybe.

Comment: @Xufox That will fail to accept "currency: word, 56"

Comment: Are you capturing the comma on purpose? And not the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently searching for `\w` which is a word character, the opposite of whitespace. Also, not sure if you're intending to capture a whitespace and commas, instead of the number values. This captures only the word and the numbers.

```
<CURRENCY:\s+?(.+)\s*,\s*(\d+)(?:\s*(\d+))?>
```

I find [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to be helpful when debugging these things.

Answer (score 0):

does this help?

```
<(?:currency)\:\s*\w(\w|\s)+,\s*\d+(\s*|\d+)*>
```

Comment: This accepts: <currency: , 56>

Not sure that should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
<currency: ((\w+\s*)*), (\d+)>
```

Answer (score -1):

another one:

```
<(?:currency:)\s([\w\s]*),\s\d+>
```

if don't want to capture empty string, change `*` to `+`

Also you don't need the non capturing group ?:

```
<currency:\s([\w\s]*),\s\d+>
```

would do the same.

Comment: This too accepts: <currency: , 56>  
Not sure that should be accepted.

Comment: @Ingrid it should capture `word` without spaces.  With what regex are you testing?

Comment: Rubular.com. It fails to capture when there is no space between word and the comma, which, going by the initial regex, should be captured.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

```
<(currency):[ ]*(\w+(\s+\w+)*\s*,\s*\d+(\s*\d+)*)>
```

Not sure what "?:" does, so you may want:

```
<(?:CURRENCY):[ ]*(\w+(\s+\w+)*\s*,\s*\d+(\s*\d+)*)>
```

Comment: "?:" is a non-capturing group

Comment: `?:` is a non-capturing group marker, so you can group things but not capture them. I suspect you may have been downvoted for answering a question, while claiming not to understand the topic...

Comment: I find this community a little surprising - initially at least, mine was the only answer that was functionally right (although a little redundant) yet it is has the lowest votes.